# How to edit docker container files remotely

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a server in my company running a docker hosting a website, how can I edit the files of my website from my home using my PC? I can ssh to the server and go to the docker container then edit the files using vim or nano, but I'm not familiar with those editors, is there a way I can do this using vscode like edit files on my local machine?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the VS extension *Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files* and edit from VS code.

[REMOTE SSH VS CODE EXTENSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutGx.png)